# PHP function does not returning value

Tags: php, google-api

I am trying to fetch some data from google API and have called API for interval when I am printing my result into the function above return I am getting result but not getting actual location *(first code)*. I am unable to understand why this is.

```
  $cSession = curl_init();
          //step2
          curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$latitude&radius=500&key=My_key);
          curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
          curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

          //step3
          $result=curl_exec($cSession);
          $abc=curl_error($cSession);
          //step4
          curl_close($cSession);

          $res=json_decode($result);
//           echo '<pre>';
//           print_r($res);exit;
          $place_array[]=$res->results;
          $result1=array();
          if(isset($res->next_page_token) && $res->next_page_token!=''){
            $result1=$this->getPageNext($res->next_page_token,$place_array,$latitude);
          }
          else{
            $result1=$place_array;
          }
```

My function is:

```
            public function getPageNext($next_page_url,$place_array,$latitude){

            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            sleep(2);
            $cSession = curl_init();

            //step2
            curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_URL,"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$latitude&radius=500&key=AIzaSyBgEtE4_8jNbVrC356EXr53NihsB-clR2k&pagetoken=$next_page_url");
            curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
            curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            //step3
            $result=curl_exec($cSession);
            $abc=curl_error($cSession);
            //step4
            curl_close($cSession);
//              echo '<hr>';
//              echo "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$latitude&radius=500&&key=mykey-clR2k&pagetoken=$next_page_url";
//              echo '<br>';
            $res=json_decode($result);
//              exit;
            $place_array[]=$res->results;
            if(isset($res->next_page_token) && $res->next_page_token!=''){
//                  echo 1;
                $this->getPageNext($res->next_page_token,$place_array,$latitude);
            }
            else{
//                  echo '<pre>';
//                  print_r($place_array);exit;
                return json_encode($place_array);exit;
            }

        }
```

Comment: When you write a question about an error, __always__ include details of the error. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: done no error r coming

Comment: Are you sure that arguments `$next_page_url,$place_array,$latitude` are not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve this by getting error from curl_error